# 4 toggle buttons speak javascript to each other but none of them are good listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

***update at the bottom***

There are 4 `divs` that are set to look like `toggle buttons`. When a button is toggled on:

> -it is animated as a pressed button,
>
> -it retrieves some content and it places that content into a box, and then
>
> -it returns a value of 1 to an array.
>
> (no problem.)

**Problem:**
When there is already one button button pressed, I don't understand how to toggle the first button off without also turning the other one off or affecting the other buttons. How can I pass the output of one button to the others so they know *who* they have to turn off when they turn on?

My solution thus far has been to create 2 arrays:

```
var arrayValues [ a, b, c, d]; //the values of each button state: [0,0,0,0] <-all off | all on-> [1,1,1,1]
var addedValues = [a + b + c + d]; //the values of each array item added together: [0+0+0+0]= 0 <-all off | all on-> [1,1,1,1]=4
```

and then

```
if (addedValues = 0) {
console.log("cool, nothing is pressed yet. I am going to return true, but where does that return value go? How can I access it?");
return true;

} else if (addedValues > 1) {
console.log("ok I now know that at least one button has already been pressed, but how can I tell the other buttons which one was already pressed?");
}
```

For example if the first button is toggled on
    arrayValues = [1,0,0,0]

and now the second button has been toggled on so it says
    arrayValues = [1,1,0,0]

but how can I pass that information into all of the buttons? This next part is obviously flawed but it's the only thing I could think of doing:

```
} else if(addedValues >= 2) {

        arrayValues[0] = arrayValues[0] - 1;
        arrayValues[1] = arrayValues[1] - 1;
        arrayValues[2] = arrayValues[2] - 1;
        arrayValues[3] = arrayValues[3] - 1;

}
```

so now, the only values that are not negative are the two buttons in active states... but that does nothing for because we already knew that. How can I tell the buttons which button to subtract 1 from without affecting any of the other buttons?

**Update**: To see the madness in context http://jsfiddle.net/Luhring/EjW7A/23/

***update: ***
Just to clarify: the buttons aren't only just toggling their appearances, they're changing other content displayed on the page:
When you click each button the content changes. each button has 1 original group of original content  that is toggled on/off with the button. like changing the channel on a tv screen with a remote control.

so if button 1 is pressed, when button 2 is pressed button 1 must turn off (removing its' content and animating back up to its' original position) in order to allow button 2's stuff to display.

shout out to @nbrooks for writing 4 lines of code that more or less did as much as I did in +100. Still not solved but his is WAY more efficient than mine (you can see his version here: http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/20/ ) )

Comment: I can hear your code screaming "*refactor me please!*". No need to have 4 functions and 4 classes which are supposed to do the exactly same thing.

Comment: You seem like a beginner to me... Or you like to overthink things way too much.

Comment: It get's out of control so quickly and so easily.

Comment: @Derija93 dude, I am both a beginner AND I overthink things too much. If you think this was bad, you should see the other one: http://jsfiddle.net/TSFbZ/ and that's trimmed down fromt the one I have here locally.

Comment: Lol, you're not the only one to overthink things too much. `=]` +1 for the taking the time to trim it down and making a fiddle.

Comment: Did you really give an element the ID `dicks`? ... Let's just move on, please. xD Sorry that I couldn't help more. The others already answered. However, I'd recommend you practice something with pure JavaScript first before using jQuery, just for the beginning, to get into it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Updated Demo, according to new reqs:**](http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/24/) http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/24/

```
$(function() {
    $('.plain').click(function() {
        var newClassName = $(this).is('.selected') ? '' : this.id;
        if ($(this).is('#content')) return;
        $(this).toggleClass('selected', 1000);
        $('#content').attr('class', 'plain '+newClassName);
        $('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');       
    });
});​
```

---

[**Update to your fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/18/)

The best way to do this is just give the elements a common class, to which you can bind a click handler and a css rule. This will accomplish your function of only having one button being pressed at a time, plus the ability to turn it on/off without affecting the others.

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('.plain').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
         $('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');       
    });
});​
```

HTML

```
<div id="a" class="plain">
    <p>A</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.plain {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 20px; text-align:center; float: left;
    font-size: 100px; color:#fff; background-color:red;
}
p { margin-top: 25%; margin-bottom:25%; }
.selected { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: Very concise answer and it even allows toggling the selected button.

Comment: @terw no problem, it's pretty useful :)

Comment: wait. if you do a toggleClass, how can you animate it? I was using the jQuery switchClass thing to animate the change of colors from blue to red...yours toggles, but how could i maintain the animated aspect of the switchClass? this toggles the button, but where would i put the content that has to be toggled with the different buttons? Sorry for n00b question syndrome but I cant help it.

Comment: @andrew Sorry, I don't understand the question about content. When you click each button, does the content change? Does each button have two content sections that it alternates between?

Comment: @nbrooks yeah. when a button is toggled:   1.) the box shadow of the button is animated to get smaller (so it looks like it's been pressed).   2.) the button corresponds to a set of images that are of the same class (all of the images also have a second class which hides them); so when a button is clicked, the script removes the class that hides them. 3.) the images corresponding to the pressed button (which have the same class) are displayed, and then can be clicked individually to be viewed in a lightbox.

Comment: 4) if a 2nd button is clicked, add the hide class back onto the 1st's images, animate 1st button back up, animate 2nd button down, display 2nd button's content.    so yeah...this is the reason why this has been so hard for me to do...this is my first substantial javascript and/or jQuery script. I'm an unemployed über-noob with high-aspirations and a knack for making things difficult. So if y'all know anyone in Chicago that needs a graphic/web intern/designer, I'm great at running for donuts/coffee and designing stuff. lol

Comment: @nbrooks yeah, it's just...i don't know if i'm making it more complicated on purpose or not but check here: http://jsfiddle.net/Luhring/EjW7A/23/

Comment: @andrew you definitely only want to have one event handler if they're all doing the same thing. I think I understand now though, when each button is clicked it's hidden content is loaded into some other `#content` div. But where/how is the hidden data stored?

Comment: @andrew update http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/24/ let me know if you still have any probs

Comment: @nbrooks see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836256/4-toggle-buttons-speak-javascript-to-each-other-but-none-of-them-are-good-listen for the thread

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing the submitting with JavaScript, then this should be a much simpler approach: http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/15/

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="a1 toggleButton">
    <p>A</p>
</div>

<div id="b" class="b1 toggleButton">
    <p>B</p>
</div>

<button id ="test">test</button>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".toggleButton").click(function() {
        jQuery(".toggleButtonToggled").removeClass("toggleButtonToggled");
        jQuery(this).addClass("toggleButtonToggled");
    });

    jQuery("#test").click(function() {
        var value = jQuery(".toggleButtonToggled:first").attr('id');
        alert("Toggled button is: "+ value);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Consider posting some relevant code on your answer as well. +1

Comment: 4 days, 2 three hour long tutorials, +20 hours + hundreds of lines of code and you did it in 1 line in 20 seconds.

Comment: But wait- for future people googling a problem like mine but where it makes sense for them to do so- How would you do it the way that I was doing it, if you absolutely had to.... How can you pass one the return value of one function into the input of another?

Comment: I would actually give you the response to that, but now I have to catch my plane, leaving for a place without internet for a week. But if no one else is up for it, and if I remember it, I will give you an answer in a week. But actually learn from my code, and try to think like that, much better, and more fun ;)

Comment: @Terw lol. ILU. have fun on your jet plane, safe trip n stuff.

Comment: Anyone else-- can a man get a link to something about passing return values into other functions? Just for future reference because I don't know how to do that and I know I'll need to it at some point.

Comment: You can define a variable outside the functions to make a global or semi-global variable that you can use to pass values around. All JS variables are defined in scopes (inside functions). Simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/p4GSx/

Comment: @andrew *very* simple example http://jsfiddle.net/AVQEL/ - not sure if you wanted something more complex but that's the basic idea