# 4 toggle buttons speak javascript to each other but none of them are good listeners- the sequel: stupidity strikes back

Tags: javascript, arrays, toggle, lightbox, return-value

This is the sequel to this thread: 
[4 toggle buttons speak javascript to each other but none of them are good listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814832/4-toggle-buttons-speak-javascript-to-each-other-but-none-of-them-are-good-listen)

Our heros have overcome the ridiculous amount of nonsense originally presented in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/8/ (no longer available) when @nbrooks -reinvigorated by the forces of good- conquered all of the stupidly placed arrays, functions and the mammoth amount of redundant content with his solution: 

http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/24/

We rejoin Luhring after 8 hours of poking, prodding, red bull drinking, concrete wall head-bashing at the final step of solving the epic problem of doom- implementation:

## The new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Luhring/EjW7A/38/

## Problem:

How can I insert the content dynamically- allowing each button to toggle it's own content while making sure the other buttons are toggled off and their content hidden? ex, if button 1 is toggled on (it is animated as if it were a 'real' pressed button), button 1s content is displayed in a gallery where the contents can be clicked to display a lightbox. when button 2 is clicked should toggle button 1 off and replace button 1's contents with its own.

Comment: Personally, I'd put the question at the top, and mention the rest can be ignored.

Comment: @DaveNewton Here and I was worried that "The new fiddle" and "problem" being wrapped in h1s would be too much. design, man. content. experience. they'll getcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**New Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EjW7A/45/)

Anything invoking jQuery on DOM elements must be wrapped within the DOM ready function to work correctly (this is why your `$('a').click()` was failing. Also, normally if you see yourself creating multiple arrays that you never end up using, and still end up referencing each element directly, you're making a lot of wasted effort. I cleaned your code up a bit - take a look:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //variable declaration section.
    var contentArray = ['albumArt', 'logoDesign', 'UX', 'other'],
        content = {}, newClassName, $selectedArray, i;

    for ( i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
        var className = contentArray[i];
        content[className] = $('.' + className);
    }

    //prevent links that are clicked from going anywhere
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.workTypes').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is('#centeringDiv a')) return;

        $(this).toggleClass('workTypesSelected');
        $('.workTypesSelected').not(this).removeClass('workTypesSelected');

        $selectedArray = content[$('.workTypesSelected').attr('id')];
        $('#galleryDiv').empty();

        if ( $selectedArray ) {
            // note creates #largeGallery elements dynamically
            for ( i = 0; i < $selectedArray.length; i++ ) {
                var $selected = $selectedArray.eq(i);

                $('<a>').attr({
                    href: $selected.attr('href'),
                    title: $selected.attr('title'),
                    class: "lb_gal"
                }).append(
                    $('<img>').attr({
                        id: "largeGallery"+i,
                        src: $selected.attr('href'),
                        class: "gallery cf"
                    }).rlightbox()
                )
                .appendTo('#galleryDiv')
                .rlightbox();
            }
        }

    }); // end click handler
}); //end the document ready jquery function​
```

Comment: I wish I could triple vote that up or something. The only difficulty I'm having now is trying to understand what is going on in your contentArray and the selectedArray for loop. in your contentArray is it actually creating multiple arrays within the array? like... ['albumArt' ...'other'] is 1, content{} is 2? What is the stuff after the content = {}, (?,?,?;)? <br /> ... In your selectedArray for loop, why are the $('<a>') and $('<img>') selectors not $('a') and $('img')? I've been trying to include video &/or canvas elements to the lightbox but weird stuff happens if I mess w/ the selecotrs

Comment: @andrew No the array only contains the four string names within the `[ ]`, I just combine multiple var declarations into a single line using commas (which is legal). The  `$('<a>')` syntax creates a new empty `<a>` element then selects it (whereas `$('a')` would simply select all existing `<a>` elements in the page, which isn't what you want).